# How to reuse a log4j masking converter?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

We have a service and we had logs printing for that service. I am new to log4j2 and We wanted to scrub some sensitive information from the logs. I found a tutorial to do this: https://facingissuesonit.com/2018/06/08/log4j2-how-to-mask-logs-personal-confidential-spi-information/

Now I want to hide the sensitive data in my classes X and Y. These classes X and Y use a common library called Z. Since both of my classes have different sensitive words to be scrubbed so instead of following the tutorial for both classes X and Y, I decided to add the common functionality in my library Z and use a list of words which I could send to library and mask but some how it doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code in the library:

```
@Plugin(name = "LogMaskingConverter", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({"cm"})
public class LogMaskingConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {
    private static final String NAME = "cm";

    private final List<String> sensitiveWordsList;

    public LogMaskingConverter(final List<String> sensitiveWordsList) {
        super(NAME, NAME);
        this.sensitiveWordsList = sensitiveWordsList;
    }


    public static LogMaskingConverter newInstance(final String[] options, List<String> sensitiveWordsList) {

        return new LogMaskingConverter(sensitiveWordsList);

    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder outputMessage) {
        String message = event.getMessage().getFormattedMessage();
        String maskedMessage = message;
        try {
            maskedMessage = mask(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed While Masking");
            maskedMessage = message;
        }
        outputMessage.append(maskedMessage);

    }
       private String mask(){
//logic here//}
```

Here's my log4j config file in classes X and Y:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration packages="directory.packaage.ClassZ">
    <Appenders>
        <Lambda name="Lambda">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{ISO8601} %X{AWSRequestId} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %cm%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Lambda>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="Lambda" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I created a bean to initialise the Log4j converter in classes X and Y as:

```
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public LogMaskingConverter replacementProvider(){
        LogMaskingConverter.newInstance(new String[] { "cm" },Arrays.asList("Key", "MeterNumber"));
        return new LogMaskingConverter(Arrays.asList("Key", "MeterNumber"));
}
```

Instead of scrubbing the sensitive data, log4j just prints "%cm" for every log statement. How can I make this work?